# How to download or print user profile data

Tags: users

I am using [**Profile2**](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module to create user profile. I am installing the [**print**](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module to print or download user profile data,

but when I am viewing our profile page there are not such options are displayed as like on a node or any content type.

How can I download profile page data using profile2 module.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `admin/config/user-interface/print/ui`

[image]

Scroll down to `"ADVANCED LINK OPTIONS"` and enter system URL for user profiles

`user/*`  - where * is wildcard

in *"Setting this option will add a link on pages created by Drupal or the enabled modules."* field(s) as shown on the image below. This will add print icons/links to user profiles.

[image]

If you do not see any print/pdf icons after saving your settings - make sure that block "Printer, email and PDF versions" is enabled on user/* pages in your theme. Or add it to your user profile template in some other way if you are doing custom overrides.